# How to Encrypt WAV file using One-time Pad Algorithm

Tags: one-time-pad

I am confused about what parameters that I must encrypt on a WAV file.

If the file is text, it's only required to convert the character to ASCII code; if picture, just encrypt the pixel. 
What is the corresponding parameter for audio files, especially WAV files?

Comment: What's wrong with all the standard techniques suitable to encrypt any file regardless of content? E.g. [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode?

Comment: This is maybe the third question only in this week with that same wrong issue: "how to use some specific scheme to encrypt some specific type of file"... People are not understanding that cryptosystems (almost all the time) only deal with bits and that WAV, MP3, texts, etc, are only bits... Also, people are not knowing about modes of operations, hybrid model, etc... Is this a lack of effort from people that are studying or this is really confusing and not well explained on textbooks? What is going on?  :\

Comment: @Vitor The reason you're despairing is classic Kierkegaard. It's not the text books. It's this forum and your internal rejection of the idea that it's an open and inviting site for all people to ask all types of questions.  Find solace in that you're not alone. Your conflict is prevalent across most of the SE estate.

Answer (score 1):

Any *modern* cipher uses binary (bits or rather bytes) as input. This is for instance the case for AES as mentioned by fgrieu. As a WAV file is already binary data it is possible to directly pass it as input.

You may want to use a cipher with good online and random access properties for a file that basically consists of a *stream* of data as that allows you to directly decrypt any part of the file, when it is required. For that reason CTR would indeed be a good choice (but mind that CTR requires either a unique key or a unique nonce to be secure).

For toying around with OTP - OTP is generally not used in practice - you can simply take each byte and XOR the byte with the corresponding byte in the key stream. The key stream must of course be at least of the same size as the WAV file.